# numpy:doesnt give correct for negative powers

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

i am trying to convert a matlab code in numpy for calculating bit error rate a piece of code is making problem for me
this is the matlab code i wanted to convert

```
SNR=6:22;
display(SNR)
display(length(SNR))
BER=zeros(1,length(SNR));

display(BER)
display(length(BER))
Es=10;


for ii=1:length(SNR)
   variance=Es*10^(-SNR(ii)/10);
   std_dev=sqrt(variance/2);
   noise=(randn(1,length(S))+sqrt(-1)*randn(1,length(S)))*std_dev;
   S_noisy=S+noise;


end
display(variance)
```

python code
    SNR=arange(6,23,1)

```
BER=zeros(len(SNR))  
print(BER)
Es=10


for ii in arange(0,len(SNR)):

   variance=Es*10**(-SNR[ii]/10)
   std_dev=cmath.sqrt(variance/2)
   noise=(np.random.randn(len(S))+cmath.sqrt(-1)*np.random.randn(len(S))) *std_dev
   S_noisy=S+noise

  print(variance)
```

answer of variance should be 0.063 bt in python it gives 0.01
plzz help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SNR is of dtype `int32` be default. Dividing an `int` by an `int` gives you an `int` (or raises a `ZeroDivisionError`) in Python2. So

```
SNR[ii]/10
```

gives you the wrong result:

```
In [15]: SNR
Out[15]: array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22])

In [16]: SNR/10
Out[16]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
```

To fix, either put

```
from __future__ import division
```

at the beginning of the python code (before the import statements), or else use

```
variance = Es*10**(-SNR[ii]/10.0)
```

With this change, the end result is `0.063095734448`.

Note: In Python3, `int` divided by `int` will return a float by default.

---

For better performance when using NumPy, you will want to replace Python loops with operations on whole NumPy arrays when possible. 
Your code would be written like this:

```
import numpy as np
SNR = np.arange(6, 23)
BER = np.zeros(len(SNR))
print(BER)
Es = 10

variance = Es * 10 ** (-SNR / 10.0)
std_dev = np.sqrt(variance / 2)
noise = (np.random.randn(len(SNR)) + 1j * np.random.randn(len(SNR))) * std_dev
S_noisy = SNR + noise
print(variance[-1])
```